# How to remove part of string in a column based on content of another column in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have database tables that look like this:

```
Class   | ClassNumber
S       | S3
T       | T37
T       | T50
S       | SS07
S       | S4
S       | SG27
```

`ClassNumber` contains the value of `Class` and another identifier. So meaning that if the `Class` is `S`, then it means `ClassNumber` must begin with `S` and followed by another identifier.

I would like to extract the identifier in `ClassNumber`.

If I use the `REPLACE` function, it will replace all characters that match. But I only want the prefix to be removed.

```
SELECT REPLACE(ClassNumber, Class, '') FROM MY_TABLE
```

This will make `SS07` to be `07` instead. But I want it to return `S07`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
SELECT CLASSNUMBER,REGEXP_REPLACE(ClassNumber, '^'||Class, '') as id FROM t
```

Or if you are sure that it's always a single digit class, simply use

```
SUBSTR(CLASSNUMBER,2)
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96e83e1891e93519c63deb3de2160a19)